# JFace Drag&Drop items highlight

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, swt, jface

I'm having problems understanding how a `TreeViewer`'s item is highlighted while a user is dragging an item.

Here's what happens: I start dragging the bottom item within the `Treeviewer`, and the items next to it highlight accordingly. The problem is, I can't get the highlighted item from the `DragOver` event. But if i drop the item from this position, the event in `Drop` method will have the "item" field holding the highlighted item. The tree's selection isn't changed when the highlight occurs

What i want to do: I want to change the image of the pointer according to the highlighted item. The problem is I don't know how to understand which one is highlighted. Another mistery to me is that in the Drop method the highlighted item will be the target of the drop (the secont Field from the top, in this case). I do not want to use `SWT.FULL_SELECTION`

Here's the image:

[image: example]

Source snippets (what i want is the functionality of `DragOver` in cases when I'm not directly hovering over an item)

```
final DropTarget valuesTarget = new DropTarget(tree, DND.DROP_MOVE);
valuesTarget.addDropListener(new DropTargetAdapter()

@Override
public void dragOver(DropTargetEvent event)
{
    if (transfer.isSupportedType(event.currentDataType))
    {
        final DropTarget target = (DropTarget)event.widget;
        final Tree tree = (Tree)target.getControl();

        final Point relativeDropPoint = getRelativeDropPoint(event);
        final TreeItem targetItem = tree.getItem(relativeDropPoint);

        if (targetItem != null)
        {
            event.feedback =
                DND.FEEDBACK_SELECT | DND.FEEDBACK_SCROLL;
            if (event.item.getData() instanceof NotAcceptableClass)
            {
                event.detail = DND.DROP_NONE;
            }
        }

    }
}

private Point getRelativeDropPoint(DropTargetEvent event)
{
     final Tree tree = (Tree)((DropTarget)event.widget).getControl();
     final Point tableLocation = tree.toDisplay(0, 0);
     return new Point(event.x - tableLocation.x, event.y
                - tableLocation.y);
}
```

Comment: Please post some code, ideally an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the `TreeItem` directly from `DropTargetEvent.item`.

---

If you would be using JFace `TreeViewer` with associated content and label providers then you could use [`ViewerDropAdapter`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/ViewerDropAdapter.html), which would take care of resolving the item.

Comment: Hey Martti, thanks for the reply.
I'm afraid it didn't help. The "getTargetItem" method (which i assume you meant for me to use) returns the object right under the cursor and therefore returns null when i don't hover above the items.

Comment: @user2245164 Apparently you can't use `ViewerDropAdapter` if you create your tree items yourself and don't set data on them. You should be able to get the drag-over-item directly from the event, though - that's what the `ViewerDropAdapter` does internally.